# What is the name of the logical sentential connective | in p|q whose value is true except at (true, true) for the truth values of statements p and q?

Tags: logic

Does anyone know the name of the logical sentential connective | in p|q whose value is true except at (true, true) for the truth values of statements p and q?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [sheffer stroke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheffer_stroke) is "nand" operator, but more commonly represented using an uparrow.

$p\uparrow q\equiv\lnot(p\land q)$